# How to automatically add validation annotations while generating pojos with CXF wadl2java maven plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, maven, cxf

I have a Wadl file with restrictions like this -

```
<xs:element name="password">
    <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:length value="8"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

wadl2java maven plugin generates the pojos but does not add validation annotations.

How to automatically add  validation annotations like @size for string validation, etc during the Wadl to pojo generation automatically from the Wadl schema?

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial solution -

use this plugin - https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools

It works with wadl2java as well for auto generation of validations like @notnull, @minsize, etc.